# SQL: nested query with tuple constructor

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I have some difficulties dealing with an SQL exercise for my Intro to Database course. The SQL standard we mainly use is the Oracle one (the one compatible with Apex).

I have the following SQL database (primary keys **bold**):

TEENAGER(**SSN**, Name, Surname, BirthDate, CityOfResidence, Sex)

ACTIVITY(**ActivityCode**, AName, Description, Category)

SUMMER-CAMP(**CampCode**, CampName, City)

SUBSCRIPTION-TO-ACTIVITY-IN-SUMMER-CAMP(**SSN,ActivityCode, CampCode,
SubscriptionDate**)

This is what the exercise asks:

> "For each teenager, born before 2005, who subscribed to activities
>   organized by at least 5 different summer camps, show name, surname,
>   birth date of the teenager and the name of each summer camp to which
>   the teenager subscribed to all the different activities organized by
>   the camp."

I do not have any problem finding the  SSNs of the teenagers born before 2005 and who subscribed to at least 5 camps and I am able to find the number of different activities organized by the camp. How do I manage to use this information to find the final result?

Now, this is my attempt to a solution (I added two in-line comments with "#" for clarity):

````
FROM TEENAGER T, SUMMER-CAMP SC, SUBSCRIPTION-TO-ACTIVITY-IN-SUMMER-CAMP STAISC
WHERE T.SSN = STAISC.SSN AND STAISC.CampCode = SC.CampCode
    AND SSN IN (SELECT T.SSN #born before 2005 and at least 5 camps
                    FROM TEENAGER T, SUBSCRIPTION-TO-ACTIVITY-IN-SUMMER-CAMP STAISC
                    WHERE T.BirthDate < TO_DATE('01/01/2005', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                            AND T.SSN = STAISC.SSN
                    GROUP BY T.SSN
                    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT STAISC.CampCode) > 4)
GROUP BY STAISC.CampCode, T.SSN
HAVING (STAISC.CampCode, COUNT(DISTINCT ActivityCode)) IN (SELECT CampCode, COUNT(DISTINCT ActivityCode) #number of activities in camps
                                                            FROM SUBSCRIPTION-TO-ACTIVITY-IN-SUMMER-CAMP
                                                            GROUP BY CampCode)```
````

As you can see, I am using a tuple constructor in the outer-most query in a HAVING clause to try and use the information about the total number of activities organised in a camp. Am I allowed to do that and would it work? (The professor did not give us any database since in the exam we will have to write down the query without being able to run it).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer to my own question since I found a correct solution:

```
SELECT T.SSN, SC.CampCode, T.Name, T.Surname, T.BirthDate, SC.CampName
FROM TEENAGER T, SUMMER-CAMP SC, SUBSCRIPTION-TO-ACTIVITY-IN-SUMMER-CAMP STAISC
WHERE BirthDate < TO_DATE('01/01/2005', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    AND T.SSN = STAISC.SSN AND STAISC.CampCode = SC.CampCode
    AND T.SSN IN(SELECT SSN FROM SUBSCRIPTION-TO-ACTIVITY-IN-SUMMER-CAMP
                    GROUP BY SSN
                    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CampCode))
GROUP BY T.SSN, SC.CampCode
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT STAISC.ActivityCode) = (SELECT COUNT(ActivityCode)
                                                FROM SUBSCRIPTION-TO-ACTIVITY-IN-SUMMER-CAMP STAISC2
                                                WHERE STAISC.CampCode = STAISC2.CampCode)
```